# Amplify Federated sign In: Validation Exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have setup a Cognito for Google login with AWS Amplify, after following the steps receiving this erro:

```
Sign in failure ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value '{some value}' at 'logins' failed to satisfy constraint: Map value must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 50000, Member must have length greater than or equal to 1]
```

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I hit this last night.